# Easiest Way to Use Django Static Url Versioning?

Tags: django, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I'm inheriting a Django app that uses Cloudfront on top of s3 as a CDN to serve static files. Currently, this app uses no versioning on serving its static files. That's really annoying because it means that Cloudfront doesn't reload files until they've expired there, and people sometimes load old files from their computer's cache. I can fix both of these through adding versioning-- serving files from something like: `cloudfront_url/git_tag/static/*`. My question is: what's the best way of configuring this? I was thinking of just using my currently checked out git tag, and adding a pipe out to `git describe` in settings.py where I set my STATIC_URL to incorporate the current checked out tag into STATIC_URL. Is there a more canonical way of doing this? I can't be the first Django user wanting to do something like this.

Answer (score 2):

Though I'm not familiar with the steps to integrate with Cloudfront, you can use Django's [CachedFileStorage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#cachedstaticfilesstorage) to generate your assets with the md5 hash appended to the filename.  This provides that anytime you rev a file you, you'll generate a new unique asset.

All you need to do is set

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.CachedStaticFilesStorage'
```

and run `manage.py collectstatic`

This will create the assets in the folder that you `collectstatic` output to (`STATIC_ROOT`).  I presume from here you upload this to Cloudfront.  Your `STATIC_URL` I presume also points to Cloudfront.

In your templates, instead of putting references like `{% STATIC_URL %}/asset.extension` you use

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}
<img src="{% static "images/hi.jpg" %}" alt="Hi!" />
```

This will map the asset appropriately to the correct asset.

See the documentation on CachedFileStorage to learn more, but it's a pretty handy thing that's baked into Django but not turned on by default.  It does exactly what you want in making sure you always serve fresh assets and not returning stale js, css, or images.

Comment: While this may work, it will need some tweaks.  By default Django attempts to cache the 'static name -> hashed file' mapping in its cache backend.  If caching is enabled then the incorrect filename will still be returned from `static` after resources are updated.  If caching is disabled, the hash has to be calculated on each access which can be very heavy.  If using this approach, you'd want to clear your cache when resources are updated.

Comment: This really won't work with S3/CloudFront as it requires a different storage backend.